# Work around for HTML stripping quotes in quirks mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, doctype, quirks-mode

when i tried to get as InnerHTML in Javascript, Firefox giving expected results. so that i can manipulate the dom elements, bu when i use the same working code, IE will strip out the quotation marks from the attribute pair. i am wondering is there any work around to solve this problem. and if possible can any body tell me why does it renders, because of quirks mode or what ?  as i have iframes in pages. 
DocType which i have in my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Expected :

```
<span id="someID">Ravi <span class="SomeClass">assignment </span>submission</span>
```

Output

```
<span id=someID>Ravi <span class=SomeClass>assignment </span>submission</span>
```

Comment: I guess that's the reason people are using frameworks like jQuery - it is supposed to have workarounds for this kind of issues

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` doesn’t trigger quirks mode, it triggers standards mode just fine.

Why do the missing quotes bother you? If you want to manipulate the DOM elements, you don’t need the `innerHTML` string.

Comment: no.. i need innerHTMl property for Selecting Range n Applying Some Styles on it. as of now it works on firefox correctly. we have iframes, in our application. so will it make differance ?