# How to get all spans in string variable, with particular class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

as i am getting tough time to list out all spans, **which having class="ansspans"**, may be one or more span with "ansspans" classes will be there, i need to get all the spans with its content and iterate through it. can you tell me how to do it, Regex, Jquery, any thing ok,

1. The content will be in **string variable** (not in DOM), as IE 9 ignoring quotes from attribute, so i cant use getelementbyclass name,and  i followed this answer, to get quotes [InnerHTml workAround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231770/innerhtml-removes-attribute-quotes-in-internet-explorer), now its displaying with quotes. so i need get all the class of ansspans, in an array, so that i'll iterate it n get the text content of each span

   ```
   <span id="sss_ctl00_ctl06_lblanswertext">
       assignment 
       <span class="ansspans">submission </span>
       date : &nbsp;10:07:51 AM
   </span>
   ```

in this eg, expected output will be 1 span object, so that i can iterate over it

Update :  I cant use DOm, as we are in quirks mode, so ie 9 will ignore attribute quotes, which i cant traverse using getelement by class name, . so , i need to match all spans in a string variable. hope everyone understood my problem ;(

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no, i not tried for this, it would be helpful, if you provide some answer

Comment: Why is your html in a string? Why are you using `.innerHTML` at all for this? Are you saying you want to iterate through any spans that themselves have a child span where the child has class "ansspans"? If these spans exist _on your page_ there is no need to get the html as a string in order to find the spans with a particular class.

Comment: i need innerHtml for Selected range, n selected text is marked as ansspans, in ie 9 it is ignoring quotes in attrivbutes, so i used above mentioned link, as it will return quoted attribute. so now i need to fin all matches which have ansspas in a string varible

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you show the code for how you create that string we can show a better way to do it that doesn't use `.innerHTML` or a string. Also can you please clarify what the desired output is? You say _"expected output will be 1 span object, so that i can iterate over it"_ - if you're talking about iteration you presumably want an array, but should the elements of the array be references to the actual DOM elements that are the matching spans, or what?

Comment: @nnnnnn when i mark the text, i will insert span class in betwen the selected text with class named "ansspans", in Ie9, it is ignoring quotes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394318/work-around-for-html-stripping-quotes-in-quirks-mode, check this, this i asked yesterady, now when i got quoted text in string, can i find all the matches with ansspans ? i need to get the conent of each ansspans class

Comment: When you "mark" the text you insert a span with that class inside the existing text, but you do put the result back in the document right? (E.g., by _setting_ `.innerHTML`.) If so, when you later come back to find all elements with that class you don't need to do it with strings, it is much easier to do it with DOM manipulation methods (and even easier with jQuery's methods). So again, please show the _actual code_ that you use to create this string, and show what you do with the string once it's created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as been said on this site before, sometimes it's ok to parse a *limited*, *known* set of xml with regex)

```
   //assumes no <span id="stupid>" class="ansspans">, and no embedded span.ansspans
        var data = ' <span id="sss_ctl00_ctl06_lblanswertext"> assignment    \n date : &nbsp;10:07:51 AM    \n     <span class="ansspans">ONE has a new \n line in it</span><span class="ansspans">TWO</span><span class="ansspans">3 </span><span class="ansspans">4 </span><span class="ansspans">5 </span>';
        var myregexp = /<span[^>]+?class="ansspans".*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/span>/g;
        var match = myregexp.exec(data);
        var result = "spans found:\n";
        while (match != null) {
            result +=  "match:"+RegExp.$1 + ',\n';
            match = myregexp.exec(data);
        }
        alert(result);
```

*(edited to capture inner html instead of whole tag)*

Comment: its ok, but can i get only conntent of ansSpan class. only text, no span markup ?  <span class="ansspans">5 </span> , then i need to get only as "5" ?

Answer (score 1):

The following *jQuery* selector `$('span.ansspans')` will get *all* the `<span class="anspans">` for the page.

If you need something for a specific element, add a prefix of the appropriate selector, i.e. `$('#sss_ctl00_ctl06_lblanswertext span.ansspans')`

If this needs to be done in a more dynamic way - look into functions like [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [etc](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: will it work on string variable ?? can you show demo in JsFiddle

Comment: as iE 9 will remove the quotes, so i need to get it from string variable. whole entire text is assigned to one string  variable, using this varibale i need to get all the class. will it possible using jquery ?

Comment: my situation is different, i can use only in string variable, can you assign span text to string, n will match it ?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you give some example, to match all the ansSpans in String

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it works, but i am in quirks mode :( :( :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394318/work-around-for-html-stripping-quotes-in-quirks-mode i asked this question yesterday

Comment: This has nothing to do with quirks mode or not, it has to do with whether you're going to try to manipulate all your html as a _string_ (generally a bad idea) or manipulate the DOM with or without jQuery (generally much easier than using strings). The fact that it even matters to you whether or not `.innerHTML` returns attribute values with quotes means you're almost certainly going about this the wrong way...

Comment: @JasonMcCreary any +1 for jquery :), though i mixed up ur solution n some other users, n got result :D

Answer (score 0):

solution using jquery

```
var tempArray = $("span.ansspans");//this will select all the span elements having class 'ansspans' and return them in an array
var len = tempArray.length;//calculate the length of the array
for(var index = 0;index<len;index++){
    var reqString = $(tempArray[index]).html();
}
```

These string values can be either put inside an array or can be utilised then and there only.

If you want textContent, use .text() instead of .html()