# get all table rows with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing

I have a HTML-String and want to get the inner html of all tr's inside. In past I have used jQuery to do it in JavaScript, but I'm using Appcelerator now, and it is not possible to use DOM there.
I have a regex that works for php, but I don't know how to use it in JS.
Does anyone know how to use this regex in JS or has an other solution.

php regex:

```
preg_match_all("#\<tr\>(.+?)\<\/tr\>#s", $html, $match);
```

Comment: Don't use regexes to parse HTML documents.

Comment: Do u have an other idea?

Comment: no, like said on the top. i don't have a DOM, because I'm using appcelerator.

Comment: see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9408540/889678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this (untested):

```
var rowColArray = [], //2D format - first key will be row, second will be column
rowStrings.match(/<tr[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/tr>/ig),
i = rowStrings.length;

while(i--){
    rowColArray[i] = rowStrings.match(/<td[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/td>/ig)
}
```

Note the use of `[^>]*` and similar:

This is like saying "match 0 or more of anything that's not '>' " and is much faster than comparing to every single character '.' can represent until a match is established. The only reason to use the '.' wildcard in regEx is to find the really old obscure whitespace characters that it doesn't represent. That could actually make a pretty huge difference for dumb browser regEx engines handling large tables.

Answer (score 0):

I got contents of almost all the divs on this page like this:

```
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
var matches = html.match( /<div>(.+?)<\/div>/ig );
console.log( matches );
```

You can try that out in console.